# shell script backing up the source directory to backup directory

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

BACKUP=backup_date
SOURCE=Arithmetic_Operators

echo "Taking backup from ${SOURCE} directory to backup directory ${BACKUP} .."

# Checking the source directory ${SOURCE} exists or not ! if not exists die
# Script is unsuccessful with exit status # 1

[ ! -d $SOURCE ] && echo "source directory $SOURCE not found"
exit 1

# Checking the backup directory ${BACKUP} exists or not ! if not exists die
# Script is unsuccessful with exit status # 2

[ ! -d $BACKUP ] && echo "backup directory $BACKUP not found"
exit 2

# Let Start the backing up

tar cvf $SOURCE $BACKUP 2> /wrong/logs.txt

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   # die with unsuccessful shell script termination exit status # 3
   echo "An error occurred while making a source directory backup, see /wrong/logs.txt file".
   exit 3 
fi
```

This is my script to backing up the source directory(Arithmetic_Operators) to destination directory (backup_date), while running the script my script was ending with message

> Taking backup from Arithmetic_Operators directory to backup directory backup_date ..
>   source directory Arithmetic_Operators not found

where i did mistake why this script is not running could you please help me on this ?

Comment: most proabably there is no directory `Arithmetic_Operators` in the directory where you start the script.

Comment: Thanks Gerald !!, meanwhile nothing wrong with script, it may be an issues with directory not on the path or directory itself is not present.

Answer (score 1):

These lines mean the script exits unconditionally:

```
[ ! -d $SOURCE ] && echo "source directory $SOURCE not found"
exit 1
```

You probably meant:

```
if [ ! -d $SOURCE ]
then
    echo "source directory $SOURCE not found" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Or maybe:

```
[ ! -d $SOURCE ] && { echo "source directory $SOURCE not found" >&2; exit 1; }
```

Note that error messages should be sent to standard error, not standard output.  It wouldn't be a bad idea to include the name of the script (`$0`) in the messages; it helps identify which script generated/detected the problem.

You have a similar problem after checking the `$BACKUP` directory.

Also, as a general rule, enclose variable references in double quotes:

```
[ ! -d "$SOURCE" ] && { echo "source directory $SOURCE not found" >&2; exit 1; }
```

(The second reference is already inside double quotes, of course.)

Comment: Hi johathan Thanks lot I have one qustion here what is the meaning of >&2 ? redirection operator is > and what about next & 2 ? could you please explain me ?

Comment: The `>&2` notation redirects standard output to standard error, so the error messages appear on standard error, as I commented.

Comment: Thanks lot again Jonathan ! now i fully cleared about 0 1 2 / Standard Input/ Standard output/Standard Error Ouput